# Unable to receive customized message sent from kernel module to user application using NETLINK_ROUTE channel

Tags: c, sockets, linux-kernel, netlink

I am working with Netlink sockets to send customized notifications regarding the state of an ethernet interface from a kernel module to a user space application over the `NETLINK_ROUTE` channel. I have gone through several articles and papers but all of them demonstrate an approach where you need to define your own family e.g. NETLINK_TEST in the `netlink.h` header or by using `NETLINK_GENERIC`. I am aware that the socket using NETLINK_ROUTE is already owned by the kernel so one cannot create it in the kernel module. I am unable to receive the message in the user space. Any guidance will be highly appreciated. So here are the two codes:

Kernel Module:

```
#include <linux/notifier.h>
#include <asm/kdebug.h> 
#include <linux/netdevice.h>
#include <linux/inetdevice.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <net/sock.h>
#include <linux/netlink.h>
#include <linux/rtnetlink.h>
#include <asm/types.h>
#include <linux/skbuff.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

int my_dev_event_handler(struct notifier_block *this, unsigned long event, void *ptr)
{
struct sk_buff *skb = NULL;
struct nlmsghdr *nlh;
int size = 0;
char buf[512];

switch (event) {
    case NETDEV_REGISTER:
            sprintf (buf, "Interface:: %s is Registered with the Notifier...", ((struct net_device *) ptr)->name);
            break;

    case NETDEV_UP:
            sprintf (buf, "Interface:: %s is Up and Running...", ((struct net_device *) ptr)->name);
            break;

    case NETDEV_GOING_DOWN:
            sprintf (buf, "Interface:: %s is going Down...", ((struct net_device *) ptr)->name);
            break;

    case NETDEV_DOWN:
            sprintf (buf, "Interface:: %s is Down...", ((struct net_device *) ptr)->name);
            break;
    }

printk (KERN_INFO "Content of Buf :: %s" , buf);    

size = sizeof(buf);

skb = nlmsg_new(size, GFP_ATOMIC);

if (skb == NULL)
    {
        printk(KERN_ERR "\nError Allocating skb for sending Netlink Message...\n");
        return -1;
    }

nlh = nlmsg_put(skb, 0, 0, NLMSG_DONE, size, 0);
if (nlh == NULL)
    {
        printk(KERN_ERR "\nError putting Netlink Message data into skb...\n");
        goto nlmsg_failure;
        }   

    NETLINK_CB(skb).dst_group = RTNLGRP_LINK;
    strncpy(nlmsg_data(nlh), buf, size);
    nlmsg_end(skb, nlh);

    rtnl_notify(skb, &init_net, 0, RTNLGRP_LINK, nlh, 0);

return 0;

nlmsg_failure:
kfree_skb(skb);
return -EMSGSIZE;

}

static struct notifier_block my_dev_notifier = 
{
.notifier_call = my_dev_event_handler,
};

static int __init my_init (void)
{
printk(KERN_ALERT "***IFM Module Loaded***\n");
register_netdevice_notifier (&my_dev_notifier); 
return 0;
}

static void __exit my_end(void)
{
printk(KERN_ALERT "***IFM Module Unloaded***\n");
unregister_netdevice_notifier (&my_dev_notifier);
}

module_init(my_init);
module_exit(my_end);
```

User space application:

```
#include <asm/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <linux/netlink.h>
#include <linux/rtnetlink.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define MAX_PAYLOAD 1024

struct sockaddr_nl src_addr, dest_addr;

int read_event (int sockint)
{
int status;
int ret = 0;
char buf[4096];
struct iovec iov = { buf, sizeof(buf) };
struct msghdr msg = { (void *) &dest_addr, sizeof dest_addr, &iov, 1, NULL, 0, 0 };
struct nlmsghdr *h;

h = (struct nlmsghdr *)malloc(NLMSG_SPACE(MAX_PAYLOAD));
    memset(h, 0, NLMSG_SPACE(MAX_PAYLOAD));
    h->nlmsg_len = NLMSG_SPACE(MAX_PAYLOAD);
    h->nlmsg_pid = getpid();
    h->nlmsg_flags = 0;

strcpy(NLMSG_DATA(h), "Hello");
printf("Sending message to kernel\n");
    sendmsg(sockint, &msg, 0);

printf("Waiting for message from kernel\n");
memset(h, 0, NLMSG_SPACE(MAX_PAYLOAD));

status = recvmsg (sockint, &msg, 0);

if (status < 0)
    {
            if (errno == EWOULDBLOCK || errno == EAGAIN)
                    return ret;

            printf ("read_netlink: Error recvmsg: %d\n", status);
            perror ("read_netlink: Error: ");
            return status;
    }

    if (status == 0)
    {
            printf ("read_netlink: EOF\n");
    }
printf("\nNo. of Bytes read : %d\n", status);
printf("Received Payload data : %s", NLMSG_DATA (h));
return ret;
}

int main (void)
{
fd_set rfds;
struct timeval tv;
int retval;

int nl_socket = socket (AF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_ROUTE);

 if (nl_socket < 0)
 {
 printf ("Socket Open Error!");
 exit (1);
 }

 memset ((void *) &src_addr, 0, sizeof (src_addr));
 src_addr.nl_family = AF_NETLINK;
src_addr.nl_pid = getpid ();
//src_addr.nl_pid = 0;
src_addr.nl_groups = RTMGRP_LINK;
//src_addr.nl_groups = RTMGRP_LINK | RTMGRP_IPV4_IFADDR | RTMGRP_IPV6_IFADDR;

if (bind (nl_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &src_addr, sizeof (src_addr)) < 0)
{
    printf ("Socket bind failed!");
    exit (1);
}

memset(&dest_addr, 0, sizeof(dest_addr));
    dest_addr.nl_family = AF_NETLINK;
    dest_addr.nl_pid = 0; /* For Linux Kernel */
    dest_addr.nl_groups = 0; /* unicast */

while (1)
{
    FD_ZERO (&rfds);
    //FD_CLR (nl_socket, &rfds);
    FD_SET (nl_socket, &rfds);

    tv.tv_sec = 5;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    retval = select (FD_SETSIZE, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);

    if (retval == -1)
        printf ("Error in select() \n");

    else if (retval)
    {
        printf ("Event received >> ");
        read_event (nl_socket);
    }

    else
        printf ("## Select Timed Out ## \n");
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably too late for you, but here it goes: `iov` should reference `h`, and not `buf`. Currently your `h` isn't used anywhere, so no wonder it doesn't work. Btw. since you have 2 mostly separate parts, it makes sense to first implement userspace part (that deals with existing messages), so you don't have to debug two sets of code at once.

Answer (score 0):

I think your mistake you should cast `buf` to `struct nlmsghdr *` and then fill the info.

```
char buf[4096];
struct iovec iov = { buf, sizeof(buf) };
struct msghdr msg = { (void *) &dest_addr, sizeof dest_addr, &iov, 1, NULL, 0, 0 };
struct nlmsghdr *h;

memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
h = (struct nlmsghdr *)buf;
h->nlmsg_len = NLMSG_SPACE(MAX_PAYLOAD);
h->nlmsg_pid = getpid();
h->nlmsg_flags = 0;

strcpy(NLMSG_DATA(h), "Hello");
printf("Sending message to kernel\n");
sendmsg(sockint, &msg, 0);
```